# CakePHP view of table with composite key

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I've a table savedItems. it has a PKof user and product. For each User that is logged in, i want to view (say, savedItems/view/23) all the items in their cart.

```
public function view($id = null)
    {
        $usersavedproduct = $this->saveditems->get($id, [
            'contain' => ['Products', 'Users']
        ]);
```

currently it just turns up null, because its only inputting the user id. How do I manage this?

Answer (score 0):

you can use get something like that :

```
$articles = TableRegistry::get('Articles');
$article = $articles->get($id);
// Get a single article, and related comments
$article = $articles->get($id, [
    'contain' => ['Comments']
]);
```

Use find method for retrieving data because it will give you all data and get gives you single row:

```
$this->saveditems->find()
   ->where(['id' => $id])
```

Check this docs :
https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/retrieving-data-and-resultsets.html

Answer (score 0):

You should use your join table in different way. If your saved_items table has following structure: id, user_id, product_id, you can do as follows:

1. Join Users and Product tables:

In UsersTable:

```
$this->belongsToMany('Products', [
        'joinTable' => 'saved_items',
    ]);
```

In ProductsTable:

```
$this->belongsToMany('Users', [
        'joinTable' => 'saved_items',
    ]);
```

2. Perform a query on UsersTable to find User with its saved products:

   $user = $this->Users->get($id,[
           'contain' => ['Products']
       ]);

This will provide you with User entity, with associated Product entities. Further reading: https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/associations.html